# Z-Index in HTML Canvas

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I was trying to make a simple game of snakes in JavaScript when I ran into this problem.

When the game over condition is triggered, the `setInterval()` loop that draws the snake is cleared, a message saying Game over and the score is displayed at the center of the canvas using `ctx.fillText()`. But when the snake is at the center of the screen when it dies, the game over message is drawn underneath the snake, making things look very messy. Clearing the array that holds the values for drawing the snake works, but I don't want the snake to disappear. I just want the game over message to be drawn over it.

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have you cancelled the interval before drawing the game over message.

Without seeing your code it is impossible to tell exactly what is happening but you could trying setting a variable to indicate the game is over before drawing the 'game over' text and testing that variable before drawing the snake.

Comment: Thanks, but I solved the problem by drawing the snake before checking the game over condition.